# How to install pylab/matplotlib in OSx?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have following error while importing pylab. I already installed **matplotlib version - 1.4.1 and OS - Yosemite 10.10.2**

```
>>> import pylab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 274, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 109, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 6, in <module>
    from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.9.0-py2.7.egg/six.py", line 199, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.9.0-py2.7.egg/six.py", line 113, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.9.0-py2.7.egg/six.py", line 80, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda/lib/libtk8.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Any suggestion regarding this issue will be greatly appreciate.  Thanks.

Comment: why anaconda? Why not just `pip install` everything?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, probably because anaconda is awesome for scientific python on mac/windows :)

Comment: Are you using the latest version of `tk`? (You can try updating with `conda update tk`)

Comment: @cel Just updated tk as you suggested, but got following error.
https://gist.github.com/nivir/f4ac46bb4f5048161877#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: @cel: really? I'm on osx and have always gone with `pip`. I think I'm missing out

Comment: @inspectorG4dget for me  anaconda come by default in osx ? Can I change to pip ? and in that case does pylab works well ?

Comment: Works fine for me with `pip`, but don't change your setup, just because one guy said so. See if someone else is able to fix your anaconda before making such a major change

Comment: Note, that `pip` and `anaconda` are not conflicting concepts. Using `conda` is basically a fancier concept of virtualenvs, with tons of scientific packages already compiled for you. But you can use `conda install pip` to get pip and then install packages with `pip`. Note, that the precompiled versions provided by `anaconda` are usually less painful to install/update.