# Matplotlib/Pylab installation issue and can not import in _tkagg?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have following error when importing pylab.

```
>>> import pylab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 274, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 109, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 13, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 7, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg
ImportError: cannot import name _tkagg
```

My system python information is following: 
OS- **Mac OS X Yosemite**

```
Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 1.6.1 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 15 2014, 10:37:34)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
```

I installed **matplotlib- 1.4.1.** and also have latest version of tk. 
Any suggestion will be greatly appreciate ? Thanks.

Comment: This is a follow-up question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064669/how-to-install-pylab-matplotlib-in-osx. I would try updating both `XQuartz` and `matplotlib` next and see if that already fixes this issue. Unfortunately the error message does not provide much information.

Comment: Also consider posting your questions in the Anaconda support forum https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/anaconda

Comment: _how_ did you install mpl?  This looks like the c-libraries never got built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Prerequisite**

Install the **command line tool** in on MacOS Yosemite

```
command line tool- sudo xcode select --install
```

**Solution**

Install the **pip** followed by the mathplotlib, numpy and scipy packages if you did not installed them

```
 Install pip- sudo easy_install pip
```

Install **GCC** with [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

Run the following command with your preferred libraries

```
 Install matplotlib- sudo pip install -U matplotlib
 Install numpy- sudo pip install -U numpy (can ignore if you already installed) 
 Install scipy- sudo pip install -U scipy (can ignore if you already installed)
```